# How do I give a roaming user account the install privilege on Windows Server 2003 through GPO?

Tags: windows, user-management, group-policy

I've been searching online for sometime trying to figure out how to do this, and I keep getting contradictory instructions. How to give a roaming user account the install privilege on Windows Server 2003 through [GPO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy_Object)?

Comment: @Erica: For server/administration questions you should ask on our sister site, serverfault.com.  There should be a lot more people there who can help you.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Add an example or two showing what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Restricted Group via GPO that can add your interns to the Local Administrators group on each workstation.

Comment: My answer was a response to Speckles "answer". I hope I didn't cause any confusion.

Comment: @Speckles - Go with what Joeqwerty is suggesting.  You want to research and use Restricted Groups via GPO.  Be careful though because there are 2 portions to this.  One portion allows you to control and replace who is in the Administrators groups on the local workstations (and member servers) and the other allows you to merge and add groups to the local Administrators group.  What you want to do is to create a domain group called helpdesk or interns and make this group a member of the local Administrators group on the workstations.  Then add your intern accounts to this group.  It works great.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but from it I think you may be referring to Terminal Server users. In such a case it would be preferable to set the permissions locally on the TS server, rather than using GPOs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking so long to respond.

I'm trying to figure out how to configure what amounts to an intern account, which would let interns log on to any user's computer and do basic maintenance. Currently the admin has to come along each time to type in his password; as one of the interns in question this is fairly aggravating. The admin has been trying to fix this, but so far has not been successful.

Currently, I'm somewhat excluded from this effort, which unfortunately makes it difficult for me to give more detail. So I trying to figure out where the f'ing manual is on how to do this so I can get involved. At this point I'm not even sure what term I should be googling, and coming to the admin with newbie suggestions hasn't gotten me anywhere.